# Popular but incorrect usage of the pattern-matching tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I suppose [pattern-matching](/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) should mean the pattern matching feature of languages such as Haskell and Erlang, but as we can see, the tag is often used for any pattern matching questions, for example about regular expressions.

Should we retag such questions? What should be written in the tag description (it is now empty)?

Comment: What is your "I suppose" based on? Or: why do you think that, for example, regex questions should not be tagged pattern-matching? Or even very generic pattern matching questions, like when finding patterns in images and signals? (I'd not expect the tag for the latter, indeed. But actually I don't know why I wouldn't.)

Comment: Wikipedia [Pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching): *In computer science, pattern matching is the act of checking some sequence of tokens for the presence of the constituents of some pattern. In contrast to pattern recognition, the match usually has to be exact. The patterns generally have the form of either sequences or tree structures. [...] Sequence patterns (e.g., a text string) are often described using regular expressions and matched using techniques such as backtracking. Tree patterns are used in some programming languages [...]*

Comment: @Arjan: it is based on knowledge that a feature with this name exists in some languages and there may be questions related to it which may deserve a tag. Obvious name for that tag is the name of the feature.

Answer (score 2):

While regular expression matching is technically a special case of pattern matching, I agree that including regular expression questions in the [pattern-matching](/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) tag would flood it with questions that are not of general interest with respect to pattern matching.

I've proposed a tag wiki for [pattern-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pattern-matching) which explicitly excludes regexp questions. Feel free to improve on it.

I see there's a [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) whose tag wiki declares it to be about design patterns. There is also a [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) tag, and a [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) tag. I'm not familiar with that topic, so I'll let others decide whether to merge them.

Comment: I think that tag wiki could work. If posters aren't too lazy to read them of course ;-) It has *my vote*!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same or at least similar ambiguity when looking at questions that were about design patterns. Often the [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) tag (772 questions) or [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) tag (657 questions, yes - there is both a plural and singular form) is added while [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) (6,949 questions) is already assigned.  Various combinations of [design](/questions/tagged/design), [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern), [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns), and [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) are rampant:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns+design - 699 questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design+patterns - 109 questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design+pattern - 86 questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns+patterns - 85 questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns+pattern - 30 questions

While [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) tends to be used more often in case of pattern matching, [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) is obviously about *something completely different*; enter ambiguity.

Reading the above, the sense of ambiguity that I was already getting, gets even more complex. There seems to be a need for:

1. a tag for pattern-matching, assigned in the specific case of the features as can be found in Haskell and Erlang ([see original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107368/168213)); as stated by wRar the tag of choice here would be [pattern-matching](/questions/tagged/pattern-matching)
2. a tag for regular expression (pattern matching), for which I believe [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to be the main tag
3. a tag for design patterns, for which [design-patterns](/questions/tagged/design-patterns) is already in use

While one can still debate over the opinion of wRar (see the comments), all other tags ([pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern), [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns), ...) don't seem to add anything to the tag library, except the aforementioned ambiguity.

Comment: Information on the number of questions with a tag is available from the tag and tag search pages: On the top of the right sidebar, beneath "Ask Question", there is a large number followed by 
questions tagged [tag-name]. I've added some stats to your post.

Comment: I don't think that there are many who would disagree with your three points.  The problem is that users don't know or don't care.   There needs to be a retagging effort to clean up [tag:pattern] and [tag:patterns], (there *definitely* shouldn't be a singular and a plural form) and then both tags should be deleted and/or blacklisted.